# how to load assets in laravel for different environments

Tags: laravel, gulp, resources, laravel-elixir

I have this 
[image]

but I would like to eliminate uring the IF statement whenever I want to load such resources.

in the above figure for LOCAL environment I have bootstrap.min.cs and app.css files so that I can debug easily.

in PRODUCTION these two files are minified and combined in one file at core.min.css (using gulp).

is there a better way without using an IF statement but still be able to debug easily using the original files on LOCAL environment?

something like app-local.css (which includes two raw files) and app-production.css (which is one file minified and combined)?

not sure if I'm clear but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: You can use webpack and gulp together. so doesnt matter its production or local you just write your css and javascript it will automatically minify and merge all JS scripts and CSS into single files. https://webpack.github.io/ check this link for beginign

Comment: but wouldn't that have to re-bundle the whole list of dependency everytime I make a change in LOCAL and want to see the changes in browser?

Comment: ah nevermind, I think I got many of my questions answered on this video :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaWKUpahFZM

Comment: I would suggest you to check how webpack works. It is really convenient for this kind of situations

Comment: I still have lots of question marks in my head but after your recommendation and watching some videos I think Webpack is the way to go and will try it out. Put is as an answer. First come, first marked.

Comment: whoops, I'm reading my question now 3 years later after a notification and it seems very naive question (beginner level). For anybody having the same problem, my assimption was wrong here. You don't have to actually use different asset url for different envirnoments (.min or not .min). If you're using Laravem Mix (as I was here) you just run `npm run watch` or `yarn watch` when you're working locally which by default will serve uncompressed scripts and then before pushing to production, you run `npm run prod` or `yarn prod` which will compress and minimize scripts for production. easy peasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Webpack` and `Gulp` combination is exactly what you are looking for.

It doesnt matter if you are in production or in local you can merge all your CSS and Javascript files as minified into single file. So you don't have to worry about your environment. Also you can use them to watch your changes in real time which is handy for development too.

check this link for more information https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: ok, but wouldn't I still have to re-compile (or re-bundle) the whole scripts everytime I make a change to one of the dependencies?

Comment: webpack can be cached.  Unless you are using crazy amount of libraries you will be fine. check types incremental builds in this link 
https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html

Comment: I'm actually using lots of plugins and thousands of lines of custom code so yep. but thanks, I'm starting to get it already.

Comment: trust me thousands of lines of custom code is nothing.

Comment: ok cool, just wanted to get those opinions so that I don't go towards another blind road just to realize later that it could be done better with some other tool ;) I want to get done with this issue and move on to the more important stuff (SEO etc).